# jsxコマンドが実行出来ません

Tags: reactjs, npm

初心者な質問ですみません。node.jsをインストールし、npmコマンドにてreact-toolsを入れました。
react-toolsを入れればnpm jsxが使えると書いてあったのですが、使えません。
npm install -g jsxをしてみてもno filesとなります。
どうすればコンパイルできるのか教えて下さると助かりますお願いします

Answer (score 1):

npmを`-g`オプション付きで使っているものとして回答します。
下記のようなコマンドで状況が調査出来ますので、試して下さい。
エラーになり解決出来ないようでしたら、実行したコマンド、その出力、実行環境などを質問に編集で追加すると、より回答が得られやすくなります。

```shell
npm list -g react-tools
# インストールされているか確認
# 出力例 ->
# /usr/local/lib
# └── react-tools@0.13.3

jsx --version
# jsx コマンドが実行出来るか確認
# 出力例 ->
# 0.13.3

npm bin -g
# 実行ファイルの配置場所を確認
# 出力例 ->
# /usr/local/bin

/usr/local/bin/jsx --version
# jsx がフルパス(npm bin -g で調査した物)で実行出来るか確認
# 出力例 ->
# 0.13.3
```